# problem with generics delegate

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I am new to c#. I am trying to declare a delegate function which takes 2 generics inputs.
I am having problems compile it. can anyone tell me what is the problem here.

```
delegate int ippcFuncPtr<in T1, in T2>(T1 param, T2 returnval);

static int ippcServerRegisterProcedure(int handle, 
    string procedureName, ippcFuncPtr<in T1, in T2> procedure)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to redeclare the contravariance in the parameter, but you do need to give the method type parameters, unless it's in a generic type:

```
static int ippcServerRegisterProcedure<T1, T2>(int handle, string procedureName,
                                               ippcFuncPtr<T1, T2> procedure)
```

I'd also *strongly* recommend that you follow .NET naming conventions - and use the standard delegates where possible... so in this case:

```
static int RegisterIpccServerProcedure<T1, T2>(int handle, string procedureName,
                                               Func<T1, T2, int> procedure)
```

Comment: Thanks Jon for the explanation and advise. I'll try to be more aware to .NET naming conventions.

Comment: BTW - why did you add Func<T1, T2, int>  instead of Func<T1, T2>  ?

Comment: @Eyalk: Because your delegate type returns int, not T2.

Answer (score 2):

You must explicitly declare the type parameters on the method, like so:

```
delegate int ippcFuncPtr<in T1, in T2>(T1 param, T2 returnval);

static int ippcServerRegisterProcedure<T1, T2>(int handle, string procedureName, ippcFuncPtr<T1, T2> procedure) {
    return 0;
}
```

See [Generic Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx2bwtw7.aspx) and [Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) on the MSDN for more information.

Comment: Hi Rich,
I get the following:

Error 2 The type or namespace name 'T1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Eyal\c.sharp\tests\ippc\ippcRemoteTest\ippc_server.cs 174 89 ippcRemoteTest

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you haven't defined the T1 and T2 generic arguments on the `ippcServerRegisterProcedure` function. Try like this:

```
static int ippcServerRegisterProcedure<in T1, in T2>(
    int handle, 
    string procedureName, 
    ippcFuncPtr<in T1, in T2> procedure
)
{
      return 0;
}
```